# Alternate Access Mapping Issues

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have done AAM for my SharePoint 2010 site. There is no issue in that.What I am doing is, I have a feature with feature receiver that reads the site url (SPWeb.Url) and store that url in a custom list.Basically assigning navigation url to my site items dynamically that is read from a custom list. Obviously the url read by SPWeb object is the url with AAM. As long as I am on my VM it is able to resolve the url correctly. The problem arises when I try to access my site contents from out side the VM because the navigation url is (AAM). How should I take on this? Anything to change with AAM?

Here is my AAM configuration

In IIS I have added a binding with host name on port 80.

In my Central Admin I have configured my site to use the same host name.

Hope I am clear on the problem.If not please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set up DNS or modify your host file with the server address?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.I doubt not. I need to check this. How this helps in resolving internal url and how should I proceed with it?

Comment: You are welcome. It is a bit difficult without knowing your setup. If you have a DNS infrastructure just add a new  record that points to your server. For local testing you can add an entry to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in the format shown in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try this on my production server.